# Unexpected EOF reading the packet type

Tags: android, bluetooth

While the Bluetooth scan function is activated for a period of time, We got an error message:

> Unexpected EOF reading the packet type!

Base on [h4_protocol.cc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/interfaces/+/master/bluetooth/1.0/default/h4_protocol.cc), it says

> This is only expected if the UART got closed when shutting down.

Why is the UART is shutting down?
Also, We found that the UART Baud Rate has changed from 115200 to 460800 while it's booting, how can we remain or set the UART Baud Rate back to 115200 in Android things,or is it possible to remain UART Baud Rate at 115200 ?

Here are the logs:

```
2009-01-01 08:00:07.091 457-626/com.android.bluetooth I/bt_hwcfg: bt vendor lib: set UART baud 115200

2009-01-01 08:00:07.299 457-626/com.android.bluetooth I/bt_hwcfg: bt vendor lib: set UART baud 460800
```

Environments:

Android Things
Android Version: 8.1.0, API 27

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
Bluetooth 4.1; Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE)
(https://www.raspberrypi.com.tw/10684/55/)

Android Studio Settings

gradle build version 3.1.2

minSdkVersion 27

compileSdkVersion 27

targetSdkVersion 27

buildToolsVersion 27.0.3